# Send POST data using Send Grid API for verification email

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, sendgrid

I am having issues posting to send a verification email.  I am using ReactJS front end NodeJS backend and MongoDB database.  I am running npm run dev to make sure my backend server is running when testing in Postman and gives me an error Cannot Post /api/verify-email I am not getting any other error code so having a hard time trouble shooting.  I am using Send Grid API to send the verification email.

verifyEmailRoute.js

```
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { getDbConnection } from '../src/db';

export const verifyEmailRoute = {
    path: 'http://localhost:8080/api/verify-email',
    method: 'put',
    handler: async (req, res) => {
        const { verificationString } = req.body;

        const db = await getDbConnection('react-auth-db');
        const result = await db.collection('users').findOne({ verificationString }); 
        
        if (!result) return res.status(401).json({ message: 'The email verification code is incorrect' });

        const { _id: id, email, info } = result;

        await db.collection('users').updateOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) }, { $set: { isVerified: true } }); 

        jwt.sign({ id, email, isVerified: true, info }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '2d' }, (err, token) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json(err);
            }
            res.status(200).json({ token });
        });
    },
};
```

emailVerificationLandingPage.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useToken } from '../src/auth/useToken';
import { EmailVerificationSuccess } from './EmailVerificationSuccess';
import { EmailVerificationFail } from './EmailVerificationFail';

export const EmailVerificationLandingPage = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [isSuccess, setIsSuccess] = useState(false);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const { verificationString } = useParams();
    const [token, setToken] = useToken();

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadVerification = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch.put('http://localhost:8080/api/verify-email', { verificationString });
                const { token } = response.data;
                setToken(token);
                console.log(token);
                setIsSuccess(true);
                setIsLoading(false);
            } catch (error) {
                setIsSuccess(false);
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        }

        loadVerification();
    }, [setToken, verificationString]);
    console.log(token);
    if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (!isSuccess) return <EmailVerificationFail />
    return <EmailVerificationSuccess />
}
```

sendEmail.js

```
import sendgrid from '@sendgrid/mail';

sendgrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

export const sendEmail = ({ to, from, subject, text, html }) => {
    const msg = { to, from, subject, text, html };
    return sendgrid.send(msg);
}
```

signUpRoute.js

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { getDbConnection } from '../src/db';
import { sendEmail } from '../src/util/sendEmail';

export const signUpRoute = {
    path: '/api/signup', 
    method: 'post',
    handler: async (req, res) => {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        // Make sure there's no existing user with that email - no verification yet
        const db = getDbConnection('react-auth-db');
        const user = await db.collection('users').findOne({ email });

        if (user) {
            console.log("found user", user)
            return res.sendStatus(409).json(user); // 409 is the "conflict" error code
        }

        // Generate the salt first
        const salt = uuid();
        const pepper = process.env.PEPPER_STRING;

        // Encrypt the password
        const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(salt + password + pepper, 10);

        const verificationString = uuid();
        
        // Store email and password hash in database (i.e. create user) - you'll also want to get the id
        const startingInfo = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            dob: '',
        }

        const result = await db.collection('users').insertOne({
            email,
            isVerified: false,
            verificationString,
            passwordHash,
            salt,
            info: startingInfo,
        });
        const { insertedId } = result;

        try {
            await sendEmail({
                to: email,
                from: 'mdolly01@gmail.com',
                subject: 'Welcome to Tool Right Please verify your email',
                text: `
                    Thanks for signing up! To verify your email, you just need to click the link below:
                    http://localhost:3000/verify-email/${verificationString}
                `
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            throw new Error(e);
        }

        jwt.sign({
            id: insertedId,
            isVerified: false,
            email, // Do NOT send the salt back to the user
            info: startingInfo,
        },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        {
            expiresIn: '2d',
        },
        (err, token) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            return res.status(200).json({token});
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your `/api/verify-email` route? I can't see where `sendEmail` is getting called.

Comment: @philnash Thank you.  I just updated the code above.  I call it in the signUpRoute.js

Comment: You are calling `fetch.put` in `emailVerificationLandingPage.js` yet you define your route as a `POST` route. Could that be an issue? Do you see an error thrown on th server side when you try to send the email?

Comment: @philnash That is a good catch I changed that but still doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Do you see an error thrown on the server side?

Comment: @philnash It doesn't send any error codes on the backend.

Comment: I notice you're sending from a gmail address. Have you performed [single sender verification](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) for that address?

Comment: @philnash that might be the problem I haven’t figured out how to do that.  I will look into that and see if that is the issue

Comment: @philnash Ok I did set that up already.  Everything is verified and still having issues.

Comment: Things in your code look fine right now, so I just have to keep asking questions, sorry. Your original question said your `/api/verify-email` route didn't work, is that still the issue? Is email sending actually working? When you make the `fetch` request to `/api/verify-email` you pass an object and you don't set a content-type. What is your back-end expecting here? Should you set an `application/json` content type in the headers and `JSON.stringify` the body of the request?